# Optimal method to determine MySQL connection latency in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm asking purely in a sense of opening a connection to the MySQL Server.

I am currently using `microtome` to determine how long it takes to make the connection. Once the connection has been made, I am getting the updated `microtome` and converting it to milliseconds.

```
//Origin Server
$a = microtime(true);
$db = new mysqli($DATABASE_HOST,$DATABASE_USER,$DATABASE_PASS,$DATABASE_NAME);
$a = microtime(true)-$a;
echo "Origin: ".floor($a * 1000)."ms</br>";
$db->close(); 

//Digital Ocean Server
$a = microtime(true);
$db = new mysqli($DATABASE_HOST2,$DATABASE_USER2,$DATABASE_PASS2,$DATABASE_NAME2);
$a = microtime(true)-$a;
echo "Digital Ocean: ".floor($a * 1000)."ms</br>";
$db->close();
```

My use case is to simply showcase connection latency between the two servers. Should this be sufficient?

Comment: If I read the manual for [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime) it says: _"For performance measurements, using [hrtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php) is recommended."_. That might be good advice?

Comment: I think it is sufficient. Also, a ping from your server to the MySQL server should show any latency issues.